# Creating a flying object that detects impact with a fixed object in Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm attempting to create a flying object that can essentially be trapped by another object placed in its path.  I'm having trouble with the hit/touch detection.

For the flying object, we'll call "bug", I've created an model with a PrimaryPart named "Primary", and the Primary part has "CanCollide", "CanTouch", and "Anchored" set to true.

When I run the following script with the above settings, things *look* like I'd expect, and I can see log entries whenever the bug touches my character, but I don't see when the bug touches my net object.  My understanding is that because both objects are "Anchored", collision detection isn't supported (even though one is the bug that moves around).  When I uncheck "Anchored" for the net, it falls down.  When I uncheck "Anchored" for the bug, it flies erratically and disappears.  Is there a way I can unanchor the bug, but still keep it under control, flying where its told until it is caught?

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local bugAnchor = script.Parent.Parent.BugAnchor
local bug = script.Parent.PrimaryPart


local function onBugTouched(part)
    if part:IsDescendantOf(bug) then return end
    print(bug:GetFullName() .. " was touched by " .. part:GetFullName())
end

local function randomGoal(anchor)
    local random = Random.new()
    local randomX = random:NextNumber(-30, 30)
    local randomY = random:NextNumber(-15, 15)
    local randomZ = random:NextNumber(-30, 30)
    return anchor.Position + Vector3.new(randomX, randomY, randomZ)
end

bug.Touched:connect(onBugTouched)
while true do
    wait(1)
    local goal = randomGoal(bugAnchor)
    local move = TweenService:Create(bug, TweenInfo.new(), {Position = goal})
    bug.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(bug.Position,(goal))
    move:play()
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution to the problem of controlling the bug when unanchored.  The bug flying looked erratic because of two issues: gravity during the wait cycle and rotational inertia causing the bug to flip and spin from other forces.  Neither problem occurred when anchored.  During the wait cycle, the bug would hold still, and would reappear a second later as though it had teleported to the position gravity would naturally have taken it.  It would also sort of tumble around on its path, which looked terrible.

I solved the gravity issue by adding a VectorForce pulling up on an Attachment I also added to the body.  I let the main body part continue to have mass and set "Massless" to true on all the welded parts.  It kept the bug stationary during wait cycles.  The VectorForce.Force "y" param needed to be set to (gravity * bug's mass), around 2000 in my case.

The flipping and spinning was handled by adding a "BodyGyro" instance to the bug in my script.  It acts like a gyroscope to keep an object from twisting around.

```
local bodyGyro = Instance.new("BodyGyro")
bodyGyro.Parent=bug
bodyGyro.MaxTorque = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)
```

I reset the bodyGyro's CFrame to match the bug's CFrame any time I wanted to change the bug's direction.

```
while true do
    wait(1)
    local goal = randomGoal(bugAnchor)
    local move = TweenService:Create(bug, TweenInfo.new(), {Position = goal})
    bug.CFrame = CFrame.lookAt(bug.Position,(goal))
    bodyGyro.CFrame=bug.CFrame
    move:play()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Two anchored objects cannot fire the Touched event on each other as the movement causing a collision must result from a physics movement. Altering the CFrame manually won't do that and achnored parts are not affected by physics.

If you unanchor the bug it will be affected by gravity which might explain the observed "erratical" movements.

You could disable [gravity](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Workspace/Gravity) or to make the bug fly by appling an upward [force](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/BodyForce) to it that overcomes gravity.

Alternatively you can manually check wether parts touch using https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/BasePart/GetTouchingParts

I'm sure you'll find more options if you dig through the manual.

Comment: You've restated why both objects can't be unanchoref.  Zeroing gravity affects everything.  GetTouchingParts would be too resource intensive if an event driven option exists .  Flying upward has promise, and I can experiment with that.  Im hoping someone who has faced a similar problem might share some actual technique.